# How to get the functional? Derivation of functional is unclear.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am referring to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.05967.pdf), p. 9.

Could somebody please explain to me how to get the entropy functional

$$
H(f(t))=\frac{1}{2}\Vert f(t)\Vert_{L^2(dx d\gamma)}^2+\eta\varepsilon^2\langle j,\partial_x\phi\rangle_{L_x^2},\tag{2.9}
$$
where $\phi(x,t)$ solves the equation
$$
-\partial_{xx}\phi=\rho,\qquad\int\phi\, dx=0?\tag{*}
$$

---

The general theory says that
$$
H(f)=\frac{1}{2}\Vert f\Vert^2+\varepsilon\langle Af,f\rangle\qquad\textrm{with }A=[1+(T\Pi)^*(T\Pi)]^{-1}(T\Pi)^*
$$
and as far as I see, here we have
$$
Tf=v\partial_x f,\qquad\Pi f=\rho(x,t) M(v)
$$
where $\rho(x,t)=\int f(t,x,v)\, dv$.

**EDIT:**

So I guess the task is to compute $A$.

Using the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int f(x,v)g(x,v)M(v)^{-1}\, dv$, I can follow [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4732661/how-to-express-the-action-of-operator-a-as-claimed), and the action of $A$ can be expressed as $Af=\phi(x,t)M(v)$, where $\phi(x,t)$ solves
$$
-\partial_x\int v f(x,v)\, dv = \phi(x,t)-\partial_{xx}\phi(x,t).
$$

This does not seem to fit to (*).

Maybe, am I using the wrong inner product or make another mistake?

Comment: It seems like this is a definition of $H(f^{\varepsilon})$, since the authors state: "we introduce the modified entropy functional", but I could be wrong.

Comment: Maybe yes. But I think they deduce it from the general theory because they refer to it before stating their $H(f^{\varepsilon})$

Comment: I'm with @BrunoB here. They specifically say that they are going to introduce this functional, which is a simplification of the original version.

Comment: And the form of the functional falls from the sky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like in your studied paper, the authors simply modified the original definition of the entropy (which is the same as you used) to exploit the fact that they are working in a bounded domain, obtaining some more solid bounds for the terms in the dissipation of entropy functional, and thus obtaining an equivalent norm to that of $L^2_{(dxd\gamma)}$ (as seen on lemma 4). In the original paper (labeled as [21]), however the authors wrote, on page 6:

"For the completion of our program, we need to show that $H[f]$ is equivalent to $\Vert f \Vert^2$
and to control the last three terms of $D[f]$. Part of this can be carried out at the
abstract level under the following additional assumption:

[...]

The boundedness of the remaining terms in $D[f]$ has to be proven case by case.
We shall therefore assume it in the abstract setting"

Ps.: I am not sure wether or not the quotation was made proprely, would apreciate any advice.

Comment: In other words: It is hopeless (or nonsense) to try to derive the functional from the original one?

Comment: I think so, but giving you a concrete proof of what differs in them is beyond my understanding. I think you should take a look at the original article and then look for where the assumption of boundness can improve the entropy definition and make it closer to this one.