# How to express the action of operator $A$ as claimed?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

I have a question regarding [this notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/christian.schmeiser/Entropy-course.pdf), page 32.

It is said that in the case of the operators
$$
Tf=v\cdot\nabla_x f,\qquad Cf=\nabla_v\cdot (\nabla_v f+vf),\qquad \Pi f=\rho_f(x)M(v)
$$
the action of the operator
$$
A=[1+(T\Pi)^*(T\Pi)]^{-1}(T\Pi)^*
$$
can be expressed as $Af=\rho_{A_f} M$, where $\rho_{A_f}$ is the unique solution of
$$
\Delta_x \rho_{A_f}-\rho_{A_f}=\nabla_x\cdot\int vf\, dv
$$

How to see that the action of $A$ can be expressed like that, say in the easiest case of one dimension? I cannot see it.

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the definitions ;) Notice in particular that the scalar product is $\langle f,g\rangle = \int f(x,v)\,g(x,v)\,M(v)^{-1}\,\mathrm d v$. Then
$$
T\Pi g = v\cdot\nabla_x \int g(x,w)\,\mathrm d w\, M(v)
$$
so that
$$
\langle f,T\Pi g\rangle = \int f(x,v)\,v\cdot\nabla_x \int g(x,w)\,\mathrm d w\,\mathrm d v = -\int g(x,w)\int v\cdot\nabla_xf(x,v) \,\mathrm d v\,\mathrm d w
$$
from which we get that
$$
(T\Pi)^* f = -\int w\cdot\nabla_x f(x,w)\,\mathrm d w \,M(v)
$$
and so
$$
(T\Pi)^*(T\Pi)g(x,v) = -\int (w\cdot\nabla_x)^2 \int g(x,w')\,\mathrm d w'\, M(w)\,\mathrm d w \,M(v)
\\
= - \int (w\otimes w)\,M(w)\,\mathrm d w : \nabla_x^2 \rho_g(x)\, M(v).
$$
Since $M$ is even, it follows that $\int (w\otimes w)\,M(w)\,\mathrm d w = c_M\, \mathrm{Id}$ where $c_M = \int |w|^2\,M(w)\,\mathrm d w$. Hence
$$
\left(1+(T\Pi)^*(T\Pi)\right)g(x,v) = g - c_M \Delta \rho_g(x)\, M(v).
$$
Hence, if $Af = g$ then
$$\label{1}\tag{1}
-\nabla_x\cdot\int wf(x,w)\,\mathrm d w \,M(v) = g - c_M \Delta \rho_g(x)\, M(v)
$$
But then
$$
g = c_M \Delta \rho_g(x)\, M(v)-\nabla_x\cdot\int wf(x,w)\,\mathrm d w \,M(v)
$$
which is of the form $g(x,v) = h(x)\,M(v)$. Taking the integral with respect to $v$ yields $\rho_g(x) = h(x)$, hence
$$
Af(x,v) = g(x,v) = \rho_g(x)\,M(v).
$$
Inserting this in Equation \eqref{1} yields
$$\label{2}\tag{2}
-\nabla_x\cdot\int v\,f(x,v)\,\mathrm d v = \rho_g(x) - c_M \Delta \rho_g(x).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation, very helpful!

Comment: Just for curiosity: Is it possible to determine $[(T\Pi)^*T\Pi]^{-1}$? I don't see how to invert it but would like to get it (would be enough in dimension 1 where $(T\Pi)^*T\Pi f=-\partial_{xx}\rho_f(x)M(v)$.